# How to get latitude and longitude on input of address in geoserver

Tags: geolocation, geospatial

I am new to geoserver, i am trying to get latitude and longitude on input of some address, but i am not successful . I have no idea how to do this. 
I have downloaded few shape files and able to load it into geoserver and load the map . Now i want to pass the address and get the lat long.
I have tried with following, please help:

package geoserver;

import it.geosolutions.geoserver.rest.GeoServerRESTPublisher;
import it.geosolutions.geoserver.rest.GeoServerRESTReader;

import java.io.File;

public class GeoREST {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String RESTURL = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver";
    String RESTUSER = "admin";
    String RESTPW = "geoserver";
    try {
         GeoServerRESTReader reader = new
         GeoServerRESTReader(RESTURL,RESTUSER, RESTPW);
        GeoServerRESTPublisher publisher = new GeoServerRESTPublisher(
                RESTURL, RESTUSER, RESTPW);

        boolean created = publisher.createWorkspace("myWorkspace");
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + created);
        File zipFile = new File("D:/IDM-Marvin/Geoserver/nyc_roads.zip");
        boolean published = publisher.publishShp("myWorkspace", "myStore",
                "nyc_roads", zipFile, "EPSG:4326", "default_point");
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + published);
        System.out.println("::::::::::::Done:::::::::::::::::::::::");


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please include a code sample that you used for this task.

Comment: No , i have just installed the server . I am completely new to this i am going through the documentation. If you have any sample code or any idea , please help !!

Comment: Which programming language are you going to use?

Comment: The proper thing to do is go through the documentation, try some things out, and then, if you can't get it to work, post what you did (with code and output) and ask for help.

Comment: Do you at least have some data that you're trying to work with?

Comment: I am using java as my programming language and i have downloaded few shape files and working with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will depend on what other tools you can use, it looks like. Based on [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65014/how-to-get-map-from-geoserver-using-longitude-latitude-zoom-level-device-width-a) it looks like you need to use WMS extension to get the lat-long. Hope that helps.